# Creating a service that needs to start after mongod

Tags: systemd

I am creating a service to run a python script in a while loop. But I Need that script to only start after mongod is running. I see that everyone put multi-user.target in WantedBy, but I saw the mongod file and his WantedBy is set to multi-user.target. So is enought to only set the WantedBy of my script to mongod.service or I need to set WantedBy to multi-user.target and set After to mongod.service ?

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you only set the `WantedBy` of your script to `mongod.service`?

Comment: yes , what would happen ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to create a systemd unit file for your service. In that file, specify an `After=mongod.service` (the service file name can vary depending on your distribution).

`Requires=multi-user.target` will only ensure that your service is started after the multi-user runtime is reached. The order of services started is not deterministic, so it would be possible for your service to launch before `mongod` on one `systemctl start myservice` and after `mongod` the next time (depending on any other Unit configuration).

`Requires=mongod.service` is also not what you want:

> Note that this dependency type does not imply that the other unit always has to be in active state when this unit is running. Specifically: failing condition checks (such as ConditionPathExists=, ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=, … — see below) do not cause the start job of a unit with a Requires= dependency on it to fail. Also, some unit types may deactivate on their own (for example, a service process may decide to exit cleanly, or a device may be unplugged by the user), which is not propagated to units having a Requires= dependency. Use the BindsTo= dependency type together with After= to ensure that a unit may never be in active state without a specific other unit also in active state (see below).

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html